# Flash Drive won't connect to steam

Tags: steam

I'm on my HP Chromebook 14. Recently I installed Dota 2 from steam onto my flash drive. Everything was working fine until I decided to turn my computer off since it was really hot. When I logged back on and went into steam, Dota 2 wasn't in my library. So, I went to Steam ➜ Settings ➜ Downloads ➜ Steam Library Folders(I noticed my flash drive wasn't in there) So I hit "Add Library Folder" to add it. Dota 2 is installed under `media/mysteamusb` so I went there and then hit "select" to add it but I got this:

[image]

Anyone know how I can get Steam to add my flash drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type this in terminal:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/mysteamusb
```

Then go back to Steam ➜ Settings ➜ Downloads ➜ Steam Library Folders ➜ Add Library Folder ➜ Click media ➜ mysteamusb

And now it should be added and your games should be in your library.